# Geopackage not rendering polygons to map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geopackage

The code to create the map:

```
 <div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 700px"></div>
 <script> 
    var map = L.map('map').setView([0,0], 1);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.ey31IjoibnVtaW51czEiLCJhIjoiY2treTN3YzduekdwMDJubXNhMWNpemdicyJ9.McJEAeE0Jbj999Oz4pbsZg', {
        attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    var marker = L.marker([18.52, 73.86]).addTo(map);
```

This is correctly creating a map. Now, I'm trying to add a geopackage containing data about states: https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/gpkg/gadm36_IND_gpkg.zip

When I use the tutorial code to draw rivers onto the map, it works just fine:

```
var rivers = L.geoPackageFeatureLayer([], {
     geoPackageUrl: 'http://ngageoint.github.io/GeoPackage/examples/rivers.gpkg',
     layerName: 'rivers',

     style: {color: 'green'}
    }).addTo(map);

    L.geoJson(stateData).addTo(map);
```

And, when I upload this state geopackage to the geopackage viewer https://ngageoint.github.io/geopackage-js/, it draws everything correctly. However, when I then try to implement the same thing in my map, the map renders fine but the state lines aren't being drawn on the map; there is simply no indication that the following code is even there:

```
var stater = L.geoPackageFeatureLayer([], {
     geoPackageUrl: 'assets/geospatial/gadm_states.gpkg',
     layerName: 'stater',

     style: {color: 'red'}
    }).addTo(map);
```

I thought maybe it was because there are multiple layers in the gpkg file and I wasn't correctly specifying on or something, so I downloaded the layer I wanted from the GeoPackage Viewer as a geojson file, and that isn't working either. Does anyone have any insight as to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making up the name of the `stater` layer.

I've downloaded (and uncompressed) part of the GADM dataset, and to see which named layers it contains, and then I've run [`ogrinfo`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html) on it:

```
$ wget https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/gpkg/gadm36_ESP_gpkg.zip
 [snip]
 2021-02-15 10:49:45 (3,56 MB/s) - “gadm36_ESP_gpkg.zip” saved [9767512/9767512]

$ unzip gadm36_ESP_gpkg.zip
Archive:  gadm36_ESP_gpkg.zip
  inflating: gadm36_ESP.gpkg         
  inflating: license.txt  

$ ogrinfo gadm36_ESP.gpkg 

INFO: Open of `gadm36_ESP.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.
1: gadm36_ESP_0 (Multi Polygon)
2: gadm36_ESP_1 (Multi Polygon)
3: gadm36_ESP_2 (Multi Polygon)
4: gadm36_ESP_3 (Multi Polygon)
5: gadm36_ESP_4 (Multi Polygon)
```

...so that geopackage has five different themed layers, named `gadm36_ESP_0` through `gadm36_ESP_5`.

Now, I can put that file up in a small webserver and set up some basic Leaflet example to load data from **a layer in the geopackage that I know exists**:

```js
var provinces = L.geoPackageFeatureLayer([], {
     geoPackageUrl: 'https://ivan.sanchezortega.es/cors/2021-02-15-gpkg/gadm36_ESP.gpkg',
     layerName: 'gadm36_ESP_2',

     style: {color: 'red'}
}).addTo(map);
```

...and the [live example](https://plnkr.co/edit/xQDdh1enyPe2dQ2y) works as expected:

[image: working live example]

So:

- Do check the structure of your geopackage, and know which named layers it contains.
- Always check your [browser's console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) for errors, because

  - A bad layer name will result in a "NULL geometry column error"
  - The web server hosting the geopackage might be misconfigured (e.g. HTTPS or CORS issues)

Comment: many, many thanks, you solved two issues for me: I had a CORS issue AND I was using the wrong layer name.

Comment: Is there anyway to peek inside a geopackage file to see the names of the various polygons within and then reference them within the code? Like, for example, if I want to change the colours of polygons representing states with a name starting with the letter 'A' do you have any suggestions as to how I might best do that?

Comment: That's a different question. Please refrain from asking complex questions in comments.

Comment: alright; I've posted a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66208220/dereferencing-features-in-geopackages) if you can and want to answer it